# in jquery countdown timer when time ended getting error Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'call' of undefined

Tags: jquery, html

this is the code of countdown timer.

```
 <div id="countdown">
  <p class="days">00</p>
  <p class="timeRefDays">days</p>
  <span class="hours">00</span>
  <p class="timeRefHours">hours</p>
  <span class="minutes">00</span>
  <p class="timeRefMinutes">minutes</p>
  <span class="seconds">00</span>
  <p class="timeRefSeconds">seconds</p>
</div>
```

javascript

```
(function (e) {
    e.fn.countdown = function (t, n) {
        function i() {
            eventDate = Date.parse(r.date) / 1e3;
            currentDate = Math.floor(e.now() / 1e3);
            if(eventDate < currentDate) {
                n.call(this);
                clearInterval(interval);
                alert('end');
            }
            seconds = eventDate - currentDate;
            days = Math.floor(seconds / 86400);
            seconds -= days * 60 * 60 * 24;
            hours = Math.floor(seconds / 3600);
            seconds -= hours * 60 * 60;
            minutes = Math.floor(seconds / 60);
            seconds -= minutes * 60;
            days == 1 ? thisEl.find(".timeRefDays").text("day") : thisEl.find(".timeRefDays").text("days");
            hours == 1 ? thisEl.find(".timeRefHours").text("hour") : thisEl.find(".timeRefHours").text("hours");
            minutes == 1 ? thisEl.find(".timeRefMinutes").text("minute") : thisEl.find(".timeRefMinutes").text("minutes");
            seconds == 1 ? thisEl.find(".timeRefSeconds").text("second") : thisEl.find(".timeRefSeconds").text("seconds");
            if(r["format"] == "on") {
                days = String(days).length >= 2 ? days : "0" + days;
                hours = String(hours).length >= 2 ? hours : "0" + hours;
                minutes = String(minutes).length >= 2 ? minutes : "0" + minutes;
                seconds = String(seconds).length >= 2 ? seconds : "0" + seconds;
            }
            //if(days==00 && hours==00 && minutes==00 && seconds==00)
            //{
            // alert("end");
            //}
            if(!isNaN(eventDate)) {
                thisEl.find(".days").text(days);
                thisEl.find(".hours").text(hours);
                thisEl.find(".minutes").text(minutes);
                thisEl.find(".seconds").text(seconds)
            } else {
                alert("Invalid date. Example: 30 Tuesday 2013 15:50:00");
                clearInterval(interval);
            }
        }
        thisEl = e(this);
        var r = {
            date: null,
            format: null
        };
        t && e.extend(r, t);
        i();
        interval = setInterval(i, 1e3);
        //i();
    }
})(jQuery);
$(document).ready(function () {
    function e() {
        var e = new Date;
        e.setDate(e.getDate() + 60);
        dd = e.getDate();
        mm = e.getMonth() + 1;
        y = e.getFullYear();
        futureFormattedDate = mm + "/" + dd + "/" + y;
        return futureFormattedDate
    }
    $("#countdown").countdown({
        date: "30 april 2014 16:57:00", // Change this to your desired date to countdown to
        format: "on"
    });
});
```

when time ended or executing code after end of time getting error **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'call' of undefined** instead of message "end";
please help me.

Answer (score 0):

try to modify the part like this

```
if (eventDate < currentDate) {
 alert('end');     
 n.call(this);
 clearInterval(interval);
}
```

May be this would produce alert. Its because the exception happens long before the controller reaches the alert command. Im not sure. I didnt have a good look at the code though.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are not passing the callback function to `countdown`(which is the second argument to `e.fn.countdown` - `n`). So check whether `n` is a function before calling `n.call(this);` like

```
if (eventDate < currentDate) {
    if (e.isFunction(n)) {
        n.call(this);
    }
    clearInterval(interval);
    alert('end');
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/wFT4z/)